# Using Material Button attributes in styles

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

i am trying to define custom style for com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton in order to reuse it in whole application, but i cannot add app:cornerRadius attributes to style defined by me.
Is it possible somehow?
Button attributes which i want to move to style:

```
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:cornerRadius="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordInput" />
```

What i want to achieve in order to use it as a style for all buttons:

```
    <style name="CustomMaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">280dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">80dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
        <item name="app:cornerRadius">30dp</item>
    </style>
```

And use it like that:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            style="@style/CustomMaterialButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordInput" />
```

Comment: use android:buttonCornerRadius

Comment: @SambitMallick it requires API 28.
I need to integrate with 23 API

Comment: Remove the `app` prefix; just `name="cornerRadius"`. You don't need it (can't use it, actually) in styles and themes.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you. It works. I didn't expect it to be that easy. I didn't even think to try it. But could you also tell me if my approach is a good practice?

Comment: Yeah, sure, that's exactly what styles are for; consistent properties on multiple `View`s without having to repeat yourself everywhere.